# Find the sixth side of hexagon.

Tags: geometry

You are given a hexagon inscribed in a circle. If the lengths of $5$ sides taken in order are $3,4,6,8$ and $7$ units, find the length of $6^\text{th}$ side.

Not got the slightest of idea how to proceed, so I can't show my attempts.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why there has to be a unique solution. I'd think many values between $0$ and $3+4+6+8+7$ would be possible depending on the size of the circle.

Comment: As said by @AlexisOlson this question has too many answers so i vote to close.

Comment: If we knew the radius of the circle (and interpret "inscribed" in that circle to mean all six vertices are on its circumference), then the sixth side would be unique determined.

Answer (score 3):

Any length $\geq 0$ and less than 28 (the sum of the lengths of the other sides) appears as possible. In the following figure, I could move the point $A$ and obtain all possible lengths for the sixth side.
[image]

Comment: except you couldn't have a 6th side $\geq28$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks. Any length greater than 0 and less than 28 is attainable.

Comment: @alex.jordan , you will change the side with length 3 by moving point A.

Comment: This is mistaken: A length greater than $3+4+6+8+7 = 28$ is impossible. $\qquad$

Comment: No, the side lengths $3,4,6,8,7$ do not change when you keep the center of the circle fixed and vary the radius by moving $A$. One way to create this picture in Geogebra is as follows. Draw a big enough circle. Choose an arbitrary point on the circumference. Take a compass of radius 3 and mark the next vertex $B$ at a distance 3 from $A$. Now, take a compass of radius 4 and mark the next vertex $C$ at a distance 4 from $B$. Repeat this for the other vertices. Now, $A$ is a free point but other points created are bound to $A$. Thus the lengths do not change when we move $A$.

Comment: Can we find a relation between radius and sixth side.  I imagine we can and I imagine it is 1 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

If the radius of the circle is $r$, the sixth side length is $s$, and you label the central angles $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_6$, then using the Law of Cosines

$$\begin{align}
2\pi&=\theta_1+\ldots+\theta_5+\theta_6\\
2\pi&=\arccos\left(1-\frac{3^2}{2r^2}\right)+\ldots+\arccos\left(1-\frac{7^2}{2r^2}\right)+\arccos\left(1-\frac{s^2}{2r^2}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

This allows you to solve for $s$ in terms of $r$:

$$
\begin{align}
s&=\sqrt{2r^2\left(1-\cos\left(2\pi-\left(\arccos\left(1-\frac{3^2}{2r^2}\right)+\ldots+\arccos\left(1-\frac{7^2}{2r^2}\right)\right)\right)\right)}\\
s&=r\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\arccos\left(1-\frac{3^2}{2r^2}\right)+\ldots+\arccos\left(1-\frac{7^2}{2r^2}\right)\right)}\\
\end{align}$$

If you follow the instances of $r$ in this expression, as each instance of $r$ would grows larger, so would $s$. In other words, it is clear (after thinking through all the negations and inversions) that $s$ is an increasing function of $r$.

In particular, it's not constant. So for each radius $r$ where this expression is defined and that sum of $\arccos$ terms does not exceed $2\pi$, there is a different value for the sixth side length $s$.

In theory you can also solve for $r$ in terms of $s$, since $s$ is an increasing function of $r$. But I don't think I want to.